# Rails validation is still firing despite unless option evaluating to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, devise, devise-invitable

I use `devise_invitable` in my app to allow users to send invitations. I realized a bad case in which a user has been invited but ignores the invitation and later returns to the app to sign up on their own. Because `devise_invitable` handles invitations by creating a new `user` using the provided email address for the invitation, my uniqueness validation on the email field will cause Rails to complain, telling the user that the email address is already taken.

I'm trying to write some logic to handle this case. I see two paths - either figure a way to detect this and destroy the previously created user and allow the new one to be created, or detect the user was invited and execute another flow. I've decided to implement the second option, as I'd like to still utilize the invitation if possible.

My limited experience has me questioning if what I've written will work, but I can't actually fully test it because the Rails validation on the email is triggered. I've made sure Devise's `:validatable` module is inactive. I created a method that (I think) will detect if a user was invited and in that case the uniqueness validation should be skipped.

```
#user.rb
...
validates :email, uniqueness: true, unless: :was_invited?

...
def was_invited?
  if self.invitation_sent_at.present? && self.sign_in_count == 0
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

FWIW, I had originally written this in shorthand rather than breaking out the if/else, but I wanted to be very explicit in an effort to find the bug/failure.

The hope is that once the form passes validation, the `create` action will do some detection about a user's invitation status and, if they were invited, redirect them to the `accept_user_invitation_path`. Again, I haven't been able to actually test this yet because I can't get around the validations.

```
#registrations_controller.rb
def create
  if User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    @existing_user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    @existing_user.save(validate: false)
    if @existing_user.was_invited?
      redirect_to accept_user_invitation_path(:invitation_token => @existing_user.invitation_token)
    end
  else
    super
  end
end
```

In a desperate effort, you'll see I've also added the `.save(validate: false)` to try to short circuit it there, but it's not even getting that far.

If I comment out the email validation entirely, simply to test the rest of the logic/flow, I get a PG error complaining on uniqueness because of an index on the email address - I don't want to tear all this apart simply to test this method.

I've tried to mess with this for hours and I'm at a loss - any help is appreciated. Let me know if there's any other code you want to see.

Comment: Are you sure `if User.find_by_email(params[:email])` is ever true?  It seems that the code inside the `if` is never reached. Could you post your form and the submitted `params` from your log? (Shouldn't it be `params[:user][:email]`??) What you're doing in your create action is strange: you're fetching an existing user and then calling `save` on it, which is useless because you didn't change anything.

Comment: @Mischa - yes, that was the problem! I was (foolishly) executing a properly constructed query by  missing the `[:user]` part and thusly not finding a user, so the rest of the logic was skipped. And you are right, the save was mostly useless - I was experimenting with the `validate: false` to get past the email validations, but it's unnecessary as everything snapped into place after fixing the query. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the redirect:

```
redirect_to accept_user_invitation_path(:invitation_token => @existing_user.invitation_token)
```

I can see that there is no `return` which should mean that if that redirect was being called you should be getting an `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError` error as the parent controller's `create` method should be trying to render the `new` view.

From this I would guess that the query you are using to find the existing user is not actually returning a result, possibly because you are using `params[:email]` whereas if you are using the default views or a properly formatted form it should be `params[:user][:email]`.

Comment: You were exactly correct - I wasn't properly querying the hash to get the `user`, so it was searching for an email of NULL, thusly not properly catching the rest of the logic. Everything works beautifully now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give more responsibilities to your controller...

If you find the user, use that, else create a new one. Assuming your form appears with `http://yourapp/users/new`, change it in your routes to `http://yourapp/users/new/:email`, making the user input their email before advancing to the form.

```
def new
    @existing_user = User.find_by_email("#{params[:email]}.#{params[:format]}") || User.new
    if @existing_user.was_invited? # will only work for existing user
        redirect_to accept_user_invitation_path(:invitation_token => @existing_user.invitation_token)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def create
    # do maybe something before saving
    if @existing_user.save(user_params)
        # do your magic
    else
        render 'new', notice: "Oops, I didn't save"
    end
end
```

Comment: I did try this just in case, but this didn't fix the issue for me. There is some useful stuff in here for refactoring the create method, but first and foremost was the issue from the question - the app doesn't get to this code because the validation is running agains the form and the uniqueness validation fails. I have to get past that first.

Comment: In which case you should carry the first line to your "new" action in the controller and run the form_for @existing_user. That should solve your problem completely. See the edited version